# How to invert expectation?

Tags: integration, expected-value

Consider the following equation
$$
g(x)=\int_0^\infty t \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}\,dt
$$
Is it possible to write $f(x,t)$ in terms of $g(x)$?

**My attempt:** I proceeded by differentiating both sides with respect to $t$. However, the term $g(x)$ is independent of $t$, leading to a vanishing derivative on the left-hand side. On the right, differentiation under the integral sign results in
$$ 0 = \int_0^\infty t \frac{\partial^2 f(x,t)}{\partial t^2}\,dt. $$
This suggests that $f(x,t)$ could be a function whose second partial derivative with respect to $t$, when multiplied by $t$, integrates to zero over the given domain. Yet, this condition alone does not seem sufficient to uniquely determine $f(x,t)$ from $g(x)$.

Given the integral's insensitivity to the form of $f(x,t)$ for a fixed $g(x)$, additional constraints or information about $f(x,t)$ seem necessary to make further progress.

Comment: Neither side depends on $t$. The RHS is a function of $x$, and $t$ is just a `dummy variable'.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley Makes sense, but still $f(x,t)$ depends on a variable $t$. Is there any way of rewriting it for $f$? If not, why not?

Comment: [Previous version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798613/how-to-invert-the-expectation-formula) of question

Comment: When $g$ and $f$ do not depend on $x$ and $g\equiv 1$ can you imagine the zillions of integrands whose integral over $(0,\infty)$ equals one? This should quickly answer the question if $f$ can we written "in terms" of $g\,.$ On the contrary: when you write that integral as a Laplace transform you might get into business.

Comment: @KurtG. Interesting, how would one write it as Laplace transform? I am happy to try it, but I am afraid I am not too familiar with it.

Comment: To be precise: if your integrant is of the form $e^{-xt}h(t)$ instead of $t\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}\,.$ This is certainly a restriction. What a Laplace transform is you can look up in Wikipedia and when it is possible to invert it.